# How to Remove <uiComponent> Tag

Tags: admin, layout, uicomponent

Is it possible to **remove** this tag which was declared in another extension?

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <uiComponent name="library_authors_list"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I tried using `remove="true"` but it didn't work.

Comment: I think it's better to override its layout file from there you can remove it

Comment: How do I remove it though? I tried simply deleting the <uiCompontent> tag in my new file but it didn't work.

Comment: did you run static view files deployment ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can do like block layout remove

Try this in your layout.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="YourExactlyUiComponentName" remove="true" />
</body>
```

In your scenario name is `library_authors_list`